# province and timezoneID mapping for Canada

Tags: java, timezone, java-time, timestamp-with-timezone

I need to find time based on the province/postal code.

For a given province I need to get current time in that province.

Approach 1:  I preparing a mapping between province and timezoneId
like `"AB"` - `"Canada/Atlantic"`

And `TimeZone timeZone=new TimeZone("Canada/Atlantic");`

Problem is I don't have such mappings.

Can you please suggest me better way to find the time based on the province/postal code

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a 1 to 1 or n to 1 mapping between provinces and time zones (http://www.timeanddate.com/time/canada/time-zones-background.html). Like the USA, some jurisdictions are split between time zones. You will need additional geographic data. Have you thought about adding a time zone field to your database? For example, instead of asking for a user's province and then trying to guess what their time zone is, just ask the user for their preferred time zone.

Comment: I know it is little bit complicated. But instead of depending on the UTC date I want to use the province to get best guess, even though it is not 100% correct. Currently I can't add the field to data base.